# Sails.js controller waits for async service method

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, sails.js

I not very used to Promises in nodejs/javascript, basically I want my controller to return a value only after my promise finish running.

I have the following service in my Sails application. I'm using request-promise  module to make a HTTP request to facebook graph api.

```js
  return http(options).then(function(data){

      var res = JSON.parse(data);

      if(!res || res.error) {
        console.log(!res ? 'error occurred while loading photos' : res.error);
        return;
      }

      for (var photoIndex in res.data) {

        var photo = res.data[photoIndex];

        if (photo.tags) {

          for(var tagIndex in photo.tags.data){

            var tag = photo.tags.data[tagIndex];

            console.log('TAG_ID: '+tag.id + ' -> TARGET_ID: ' + target);

            if (tag.id == target) {
              photos.push(photo);
            }

          }

        }
      }

      if (res.paging && res.paging.next) {
        console.log('recursion in action!!');
        myself(id, target, accessToken, decodeURIComponent(res.paging.next));
      }
```

And my controller is:

```js
var countPhotos = Facebook.countTaggedPhotos(requesterId, targetId, accessToken).then(function(photos){
  return res.json({photos: photos.length});   
});
```

But the controller is returning 0 before my service promise ended, when I look to the log I can see it's still executing the loops.

How can I make my controller wait everything to end before returning, I thought that was `.then()` job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours hitting my head against the wall because this problem, I've found the root of problem and the solution.

**Root of the problem: *The Recursion***

```
myself(id, target, accessToken, decodeURIComponent(res.paging.next));
```

Once the recursion started I didn't get any promise to wait them, resulting in my problem, when the first promise ended he executed the `.then()` callback returning 0 photos in the array and releasing the controller to return before endind the processing on the other pages. And the other mistake was that I was doing a recursion in the entire `countTaggedPhotos` method, changed to only the http callback.

**Solution: *Nested promises***

```js
var promiseHttp = http(options).then(function myself(data){

  var res = JSON.parse(data);

  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred while loading photos' : res.error);
    return;
  }

  for (var photoIndex in res.data) {

    var photo = res.data[photoIndex];

    if (photo.tags) {

      for(var tagIndex in photo.tags.data){

        var tag = photo.tags.data[tagIndex];

        if (tag.id == target) {
          photos.push(photo);
        }

      }

    }
  }

  if (res.paging && res.paging.next) {

    var opt={ uri: decodeURIComponent(res.paging.next), method: 'GET'  };
    return http(opt).then(myself);

  }

});

return promiseHttp.return(photos);
```

Now my controller is able to wait every page finish it's processing and return the photos correctly.

I don't know if this solution is the best, but it works. If anyone have something to add, some best practices or somenthing, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2):

You're right when you say that this is a .then() job. When you say

```
var countPhotos = Facebook.countTaggedPhotos()
```

You're setting countPhotos equal to whatever countTaggedPhotos().then() **returns**. In this case, it does not return the number of photos. The only place in which you can access the number of photos is inside that .then.

In order to help you further, you need to provide the code surrounding your

```
return http(options).then(function(data){...
```

because in there, you're referencing photos, but I don't know how that's actually being provided to the .then() in your controller.